# calculating average values in a file using awk from multiple files

Tags: python, bash, matrix, average

I have 100 files with name file.1.netcc, file.2.netcc ... file.100.netcc. Each file contains the following contents:

```
# 4 # Number of network ROIs 
# 2 # Number of netcc matrices 
# WITH_ROI_LABELS 
LFovea_LO LLO LMT RV3A 
1 2 3 4 
# CC 
1.0000  0.2271  -0.1172 -0.2258 
0.2271  1.0000  0.3991  0.1092 
-0.1172 0.3991  1.0000  0.3055 
-0.2258 0.1092  0.3055  1.0000 
# FZ 
4.0000  0.2312  -0.1177 -0.2297 
0.2312  4.0000  0.4226  0.1096 
-0.1177 0.4226  4.0000  0.3156 
-0.2297 0.1096  0.3156  4.0000
```

Now, what I want to happen is to average all the 'cc' values for example. Each value will be averaged from all files. For instance, we take the first value from first column, first row (1.0000) to be averaged from all the files and outputted to be the average value... and so on until the last digit, which is the 4column, 4th row value (1.0000) to be averaged for all files.
So what I want returned, is to have a 4x4 table with the values averaged out for all files.
I also want this done for the 'FZ' category below it.  How can I do this?

I tried using this command:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+="  "$1"  "$2"  "$3"   "$4"  "$5"  "$6"   "$7"   "$8;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print i,a[i]/b[i];}' /Users/3dnetcorr/file*.netcc > outputs_averaged.file
```

but what this command did (i think) was average out the entire column to give me one value per column.. and this is not what I want it to do.

I guess what I'm asking is how can i average out files that contain a matrix?
How can I do this with python coding? numpy maybe?

Comment: @melpomene that was a typo.  it has been fixed.  I meant 4th row 4th column.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with awk. I'd probably write a perl program.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'FNR==1 {fc++; cc_f==fz_f=0; cc_c=fz_c=0}
    /^# CC/ {cc_f=1; fz_f=0; next}
    /^# FZ/ {cc_f=0; fz_f=1; next}
    cc_f    {cc_c++; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) cc[cc_c,i]+=$i}
    fz_f    {fz_c++; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) fz[fz_c,i]+=$i}
    END {print "CC averages"
         for(i=1;i<=cc_c;i++)
           for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) printf "%.4f%s", cc[i,j]/fc, (j==NF?ORS:OFS)
         print "FZ averages"
         for(i=1;i<=fz_c;i++)
           for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) printf "%.4f%s", fz[i,j]/fc, (j==NF?ORS:OFS)}' file{1..100}
```

This doesn't validate the file format, so should be consistent across files.
It doesn't assume square matrices. Some naming conventions `_f` for flag/indicator `_c` for counter.  `fc` is the file counter.  You may combine flags and counters but will be more difficult to interpret.

Comment: great, thanks! Should I write this code in bash?
Also, does this print to a new file?

Comment: as a `bash` script this will be very long, fragile and pointless. If you already have `awk` why not use it. Add a redirection `> outputfile` at the end to send the output to a file instead of stdout.

Comment: The output looked something like this: 
`CC averages
1.00000000 0.17263182 0.10410909 0.13875455 0.11106818
0.17263182 0.77272727 0.22058182 0.12345000 0.06792727
0.10410909 0.22058182 0.54545455 0.16238636 0.02765455
0.13875455 0.12345000 0.16238636 0.40909091 0.04199091
0.11106818 0.06792727 0.02765455 0.04199091 0.27272727`

this is wrong since the diagonal does not equal to one.  All the files, the diagonal values equal to one. Therefore when getting the average, it should still equal one.

Comment: that's odd, there shouldn't be any difference between any of the coordinates.  Perhaps adding format validation is required.  Can you test with 2 or 3 files for which you can validate the input?

Answer (score 1):

using gnu **awk**

works for multiple matrices having format `# XX`

```
$ awk '/^# .. $/{key=$2; i=1; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; next} 
      !i~/0/ && ARGIND<=100{for(j=1; j<=4; j++) a[key FS i FS j]+=$j; (i>=4)?i=0:i++} 
     END{ 
          for(INDEX in a) { 
            split(INDEX,k,FS); 
            if(!seen[k[1]]++) print "# "k[1]; 
            printf a[k[1] FS k[2] FS k[3]]/(ARGIND)"" (k[3]%4?FS:RS) 
          }
        }' file{1..100}

# CC
8.66667 0.2271 -0.1172 -0.2258
0.2271 1 0.3991 0.1092
-0.1172 4.06577 1 0.3055
-0.2258 0.1092 0.3055 1
# FZ
4 0.2312 -0.1177 -0.2297
0.2312 4 0.4226 0.1096
-0.1177 0.4226 4 0.3156
-0.2297 0.1096 0.3156 4
```

`/^# .. $/` : Matches with `# CC`, `# FX`, `# RZ` (mind the space at the end). You can modify the pattern as required. IF this pattern is matched then set key as `$2` i.e. `key=CC` or `key=FX` etc

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"` : To sort associative array `a` on the basis of keys. The sorted order is reflected during traversal.

`ARGIND<=100{...}` : This block sum up the array elements for each file. Change 100 to whatever number of files you want to play with

`END {..}` block: To traverse array and print the average of each element. `ARGIND` here would denote the number of files and hence the number of matrix elements in total for each index.

Comment: @hsayya: The output here is based on some modified input. Can you try and let me know if it gives you the desired output ?